# Empty space at the end of page

Tags: html, css

How do I manually leave empty space at the bottom of a html page?

My contents are in `div` and are `positioned:absolutely` mostly.

I tried couple of `<br>`s right before `</body>`. Did not work.
I tried `margin-bottom:2cm;` on the div. Did not work.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ or http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolute positioned div's are out of the document flow, so whatever you do, won't affect the other elements on the page and hence, `margin-bottom` fails as well, so what you can do is use a wrapping `div` with a height of `100%;` and than use `margin-bottom: 2cm;` and it will work

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #f50;
}

div { /* Using element selector, you can use ids or classes instead to be specfic*/
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxJq8/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS in your page:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 50px
}
```

Comment: that's something I already did and I mentioned it above. :) Did not work out.

Comment: No, this will stop the background rendering if the background is applied to body, bad option, and what if he needs an element below the assigned margin? will you place that outside the body? I hope no

Answer (score 1):

Try using `padding-bottom` instead of `margin-bottom` because margin is used to space between content, padding is spacing within the element, which should give you the effect you're looking for.

You could also probably just place a blank div before `</body>` like `<div style="height: 200px;"></div>` too.

Comment: No boy, The contents are absolutely positioned. That is why empty div will not work and did not.